# Where is the basis for negative tabindex being focusable?

Tags: javascript, focus

I found focus() information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) ...

> but a script can do so by calling the `focus()` method.

Is this clearly defined in the specification?

There are several conditions for focusable, but the [following conditions](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focusable-area) are most likely to be met.

> Any other element or part of an element determined by the user agent to be a focusable area, especially to aid with accessibility or to better match platform conventions.

However, since this depends on the judgment of each browser vendor, I thought that it could not be the basis that the negative tabindex is focusable.

Since there are currently no browsers where negative tabindex is not focusable, can we say that negative tabindex is focusable?

Comment: If you read the [`tabindex` description](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#tabindex-value): *"If the value is a negative integer The user agent must consider the element as a focusable area, but should omit the element from any tabindex-ordered focus navigation scope."*

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you very much. My problem has been solved. I ’d like to make the question resolved so it ’s helpful.

Comment: As a snake, I investigated the behavior in each browser, Gecko ignored `focus()` on the negative tabindex and WebKit did not. This seems to be a Gecko bug.